# my mistake caused bad links on SE howto resolve it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I made mistake in .htaccess on my site with following codes :

```
RewriteRule ^articles/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html$ ./maghalat.php?id=$1
```

That it seems it have changed my links on Google and other search engines from:
`siteaddress/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html` 
to :
`siteaddress/maghalat.php/isfahan_articles108.html?id=108`

how can I change my links on SE to old style:
`siteaddress/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html`

Note: I have changed my .htaccess to :

```
RewriteRule ^articles/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html$ maghalat.php?id=$1
```

But my issue is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't have a live version of your website - it visits it periodically and stores the results. So it will take a few days after you revert your URLs before they will be updated in google.

You can speed this up by submitting a Sitemap or increasing the Crawl Speed at:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: Do you mean my current rule is currect?

Comment: and is there any way to redirect permanently :<br> mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_artilesXXX.html?id=XXX to mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html ?

Comment: I haven't tried running your code and am not certain what you are heading for. I saw a post from a Google Engineer, possibly matt cutts, saying the crawler now prefers parameters in urls e.g. ?x=y as it gives information about site structure.

If you just want to remove everything after the ?, try something like

RewriteEngine On
redirect 301 /xxx.html /xxx.html?

Comment: Could you please say full detailed redirection for : redirect mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articlesXXX.html?id=XXX to mysite/articles/isfahan_articlesXXX.html  ?